# WPF MVVM TreeView using HierarchicalDataTemplate not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

So I've been struggling with getting my TreeViews to update properly for a long time now and so I'm asking if anyone can tell me why my code isn't properly updating my TreeView nodes on additions or subtractions.  I apologize in advance for the somewhat massive code dump but I felt it was all important to illustrate the problem.

For starters my ObservableObject class

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

TreeNodeBase Class

```
public abstract class TreeNodeBase : ObservableObject
{
    protected const string ChildNodesPropertyName = "ChildNodes";

    protected string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected IList<TreeNode> childNodes;

    protected TreeNodeBase(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.childNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TreeNode> ChildNodes
    {
        get
        {
            return this.childNodes;
        }
    }

    public TreeNodeBase AddChildNode(string name)
    {
        var treeNode = new TreeNode(this, name);
        this.childNodes.Add(treeNode);
        this.OnPropertyChanged(ChildNodesPropertyName);

        return treeNode;
    }

    public TreeNode RemoveChildNode(string name)
    {
        var nodeToRemove = this.childNodes.FirstOrDefault(node => node.Name.Equals(name));

        if (nodeToRemove != null)
        {
            this.childNodes.Remove(nodeToRemove);
            this.OnPropertyChanged(ChildNodesPropertyName);
        }

        return nodeToRemove;
    }
}

public class TreeNode : TreeNodeBase
{
    public TreeNodeBase Parent { get; protected set; }

    public TreeNode(TreeNodeBase parent, string name)
        : base(name)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

The TreeNodeRoot class

```
public class TreeViewRoot : TreeNodeBase
{
    public TreeViewRoot(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
    }
}
```

The TreeNode Class

```
public class TreeNode : TreeNodeBase
{
    public TreeNodeBase Parent { get; protected set; }

    public TreeNode(TreeNodeBase parent, string name)
        : base(name)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

The TreeView UserControl Xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="TreeViewExperiment.TreeView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:treeViewExperiment="clr-namespace:TreeViewExperiment"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance treeViewExperiment:TreeViewmodel}">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <treeViewExperiment:TreeViewmodel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TreeViewHierarchicalTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TreeView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Tree" ItemsSource="{Binding RootLevelNodes}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TreeViewHierarchicalTemplate}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction
                        Command="{Binding SetSelectedNode}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=Tree}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TreeView>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="25">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Verdana"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Add Node" Command="{Binding AddNode}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=NameTextBox}" Background="Green"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Remove Node" Command="{Binding RemoveNode}" Background="Red"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Finally the TreeViewmodel

```
public class TreeViewmodel : ObservableObject
{
    public ICommand SetSelectedNode { get; private set; }

    public ICommand AddNode { get; private set; }

    public ICommand RemoveNode { get; private set; }

    public TreeViewmodel()
    {
        this.SetSelectedNode = new ParamaterizedDelegateCommand(
            node =>
                {
                    this.SelectedTreeNode = (TreeNodeBase)node;
                });

        this.AddNode = new ParamaterizedDelegateCommand(name => this.SelectedTreeNode.AddChildNode((string)name));

        this.RemoveNode = new DelegateCommand(
            () =>
                {
                    if (selectedTreeNode.GetType() == typeof(TreeNode))
                    {
                        var parent = ((TreeNode)this.SelectedTreeNode).Parent;
                        parent.RemoveChildNode(this.SelectedTreeNode.Name);
                        this.SelectedTreeNode = parent;
                    }
                });

        var adam = new TreeViewRoot("Adam");
        var steve = adam.AddChildNode("Steve");
        steve.AddChildNode("Jack");

        this.rootLevelNodes = new List<TreeViewRoot> { adam, new TreeViewRoot("Eve") };
    }

    private TreeNodeBase selectedTreeNode;

    private readonly IList<TreeViewRoot> rootLevelNodes;

    public IEnumerable<TreeViewRoot> RootLevelNodes
    {
        get
        {
            return this.rootLevelNodes;
        }
    }

    public TreeNodeBase SelectedTreeNode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedTreeNode;
        }

        set
        {
            this.selectedTreeNode = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

So I know that the UI should be getting notified when child elements are added removed as when I debug it I can see that the get accessor on the ChildNodes property is called in both cases, yet what is displayed on the UI remains unchanged.

In the past I've gotten around this but using ObservableCollections and that seems to be what most solutions to this sort of problem point to here on StackOverflow, but why doesn't this solution also work?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are misusing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. In your code you are notifying the view that your property `ChildNodes` changed but it isn't true as `TreeViewItem.ItemsSource` still equals your `ChildNodes` property.

`INotifyPropertyChanged` will cause UI update when underlying collection object in yout view model changes.

To get `ItemsSource` updated when new item in collection occurs you need to use a collection which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

As [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx):

> You can enumerate over any collection that implements the IEnumerable interface. However, to set up dynamic bindings so that insertions or deletions in the collection update the UI automatically, the collection must implement the INotifyCollectionChanged interface. This interface exposes an event that should be raised whenever the underlying collection changes.

That's why everyone on SO advise to use `ObservableCollection`.

EDIT:

If you want to expose read-only collection you should check [`ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It works as a wrapper for `ObservableCollection` which can be made non public.

Comment: This does seem to be the problem.  However it's still important to me that I move away from ObservableCollection as I want to expose to the UI a collection that is read only.  I'll probably break out the existing list into it's own class that implements INotifyCollectionChanged interface and see how that goes.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using [ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?